# How do I create an MVC area for API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, controller, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

I created a new MVC project and I ticked the box for API.

However, I intend to create many API functions and I don't really want to fill up the main controllers folder, so, I thought this will be a good use for an area.

So, I created an area called `API`, but, no matter what I do, I can't seem to access any of the API pages.

Just to test, I created another controller called `test` on the API area, and, I can access and do everything as expected.

I came straight from MVC2/3, and then had a few years off...  I'm a bit out of touch and I believe this could be related to the `/App_Start/WebApiConfig.cs` and `/Global.asax` files, but, I have tried to edit them in various ways without any luck.

Does anyone know what is happening and what I need to do to get the API features working from an area?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to create an Area for Api controllers, but your Api controllers must derive from `ApiController` to be picked up. Instead of creating a Area, just organize your controllers inside folders and as long as the controllers follow convention they will be picked up by the WebApi.

In your `WebApiConfig.cs`you'll be able to define Routes, although I recommend using [Attribute Based Routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) instead. Then for each "area" you could create a base api controller and stick a `[RoutePrefix("api/areaName")] attribute on the class - and then for every controller in that area, you just derive from that base controller.

Here is a quick example for a "Users" api controller. With the example below you'll be able to to use the following urls:

- `GET` http://localhost:port/api/users
- `GET` http://localhost:port/api/users/some-guid
- `POST` http://localhost:port/api/users

Remember to enable attribute based routing in your `WebApiConfig` class.

**WebApiConfig.cs**

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
    }
}
```

**UsersApiController.cs**

```
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
public class UsersApiController : ApiController 
{
        List<User> _users = new List<User> { new User("Foo", "Bar"), new User("Bar", "Foo") };

        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get()
        {
            var result = _users;

            return Ok(result);
        }

        [Route("{id:guid}")]
        public IHttpActionResult Get(Guid id)
        {
            var result = _users.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Id == id);

            if (result == null)
                return NotFound();

            return Ok(result);
        }        

        [Route("")]
        public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody]PostModel model)
        {
            // Process the input model
            var user = new User(model.FirstName, model.LastName);

            // Save user to database
            _users.Add(user);           

            return Created<User>(Request.RequestUri + user.Id.ToString(), user);
        }

        public class PostModel 
        {
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            public string LastName { get; set; }
        }

        public class User
        {
            public User(string firstName, string LastName)
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid();
                FirstName = firstName;
                LastName = lastName;
            }

            public Guid Id { get; private set; }
            public string FirstName { get; private set; }
            public string LastName { get; private set; }        
        }
}
```